# Assign value on dynamic generate textarea after retrieve dynamic generate value in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using `.append()` function for dynamic generating HTML DOM.  Thus, modal is creating dynamically, so I am using `$('.modal-body' ).on('keyup', '#modal_product_details'+i, function(){}`  and getting the value finely modal_desc.

But when I am assign this (modal_desc) value in dyanmic text area field `(#additional_description1, #additional_description2, #additional_description3.....)`, that is not writing.

```
    $('.modal-body' ).on('keyup', '#modal_product_details'+i, function(){
        var modal_desc = $(this).val();
        alert(modal_desc);
        $('#additional_description'+i).text(modal_desc);
    });
```

Please suggest me how I can tune this issue and write this value based on dynamic created textarea.

Comment: from where this `i` came from?

Comment: i is row value. I have alerted i in .on(){ alert(i); } and it(i) is coming finely.

Comment: Where is `i` incrementing?

Comment: just at bellow the this code..
$('.modal-body' ).on('keyup', '#modal_product_details'+i, function(){    });

Comment: Try checking the length using "#modal_product_details'+i" selector. it will help to identify that whether the element that you are trying to select exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) instead of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) for textarea's like,

```
$('#additional_description'+i).val(modal_desc);
```

I think there are multiple id which are same if `i` is common in all `modals` so first get parent of all `additional_description` fields in a single modal box then change their values like,

```
$('.modal-body' ).on('keyup', '#modal_product_details'+i, function(){
    var modal_desc = $(this).val();
    var parent = $(this).closest('.modal-body'); // get parent here
    alert(modal_desc);
    parent.find('[id^="additional_description"]') // get all add.. desc.. id
      .each(function(ind){
        $('#additional_description'+(ind+1)).val(modal_desc);
    });
});
```

Comment: No. it is not working. The main issue, is not recognizing  $('#additional_description'+i) , but instead $('#additional_description1') and  $('#additional_description2') then it is recongnizing.

Comment: Share a fiddle/snippet so that we can see your HTML with JS code.